# Injecting OkHttpClient using Dagger2

Tags: android, android-library, dagger-2, aar

I'd like to be able to inject a new `OkHttpClient` using Dagger2 but am having a hard time. Most of the tutorials and instructions are written for applications and I'm building an aar (android library).

here's my Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface AndroidSdkComponent {
    void inject(OkHttpClient httpClient);
}
```

here's my module:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Context context) {
        final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        if (Configuration.isAlphaBuild(context)) {
            client.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

At an entry point of my library I build the component like so:

```
DaggerAndroidSdkComponent.builder().networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                                            .build();
```

but later when I'm trying to `@Inject OkHttpClient okHttpClient` it appears to always be null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm I doing wrong?

```
void inject(OkHttpClient httpClient);
```

This will inject an `OkHttpClient` with the dependencies it needs...But since you neither call it, nor have access to the fields of the okhttp client anyways this method is redundant and useless.

```
DaggerAndroidSdkComponent.builder().networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                                        .build();
```

This will build a component. It will *build* it. You still need to use it. e.g. call `inject()` and inject the object you want to inject.

---

What you need to do is update your interface to actually inject the object where you want the `OkHttpClient` *in*. You don't provide any information of where you want that client to be used, but you should have `SomeClass` like the following, where you already build the component with the code you provided above:

```
class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    OkHttpClient mClient(); // THIS is how you mark a field for injection

    void someMethod() {
        AndroidSdkComponent component = DaggerAndroidSdkComponent.builder().networkModule(new NetworkModule())
                .build();

        component.inject(this); // THIS is how you inject a field (okhttp!)
    }
}
```

Then you need to update the component to *know* about `SomeClass` that you want to be injected:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface AndroidSdkComponent {
    void inject(SomeClass someclass); // THIS will inject okhttp to your someclass object, as seen above
}
```

---

*Please* read some more tutorials about dagger and try playing with it, since it seems that you don't really understand how it works or what the different classes do. The [User's Guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html) is a good place to start.